# Are there any static analysis tools that can help detect shared_ptr<> circular references?

Tags: c++, static-analysis, circular-reference

Are there any static analysis tools that can help detect shared_ptr<> circular references?

Even if such a tool couldn't detect complicated cases, it would still be useful for eliminating the simple cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know about existing of such tools, but [here are](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2006/11/23515.php) nice thoughts about the problem:

> The key to effective object life time management
>   is to have an acyclic object ownership graph.
>   Then you use shared pointers when going down,
>   weak pointers when going sideways,
>   and weak pointers (or sometimes plain pointers) when going up the graph.

Comment: Nice lucid description of the solution.